# How to make a subplot of a table & a pie chart in plotly using cufflinks

Tags: plotly, cufflinks

Consider i want to display this data as format of pie-chart and table.

```
  result_category  percentage
0          PASSED        94.0
1          FAILED         6.0
```

Is there a way to bind the table and the pie chart using the cufflinks as a sublot(1,2)?

Comment: Why cufflinks..?

Comment: @vestland My look up on the plotly showed cufflinks to a better wrapper for plotly and easy to use with pandas.Is my assumption wrong